# Android: How to detect if users if within distance of GeoPoint on MapVIew

Tags: android

I have an application with a map and an `ItemizedOverlay`, and need to determine if the user is within a certain distance of a `GeoPoint` on the `ItemizedOverlay`. If thats the case then start a new `Activity`..

How do I approach this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have various things you need to do, I would break it down into the following

1. Obtain the users GeoPoint, have a look at [this](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MyLocationOverlay.html#getMyLocation%28%29) API it might be useful
2. Determine the distance between the users GeoPoint and any other given GeoPoint, I found [this](http://www.anddev.org/distance_calculation_between_2_geopoint_by_haversine_formula-t3062.html) article which explains how to calculate distances, its worth a read
3. If the distance meets a particular requirement, then start a new activity, for this I would suggest to read up on [Intents/Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#actlife). You could create a new intent and use `startActivity(intent);` which would start another activity, you can read more here

Comment: Don't calculate the distance yourself use the functions that are available in the location class: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html

Comment: Thanks alot.. Think I got it now :)